# QT layout manager does not recover space when hiding widget until window is moved

Tags: qt

I am using Qlabels to plot some graphs and images (via setpixmap).

My basic layout is:

QVBoxlayout  main layout via qdialog's setlayout.
   QHboxlayout (array of QLabels)
   Qlabel expandedPlot (optional expanded plot of one of the above QLabels)
   QLabel mainImage   Main image display

Within the QDialogs re-implemented keypress event handler, I hide()/show() the expanded plot.  When I hide() the expandedPlot, the layoutmanager recovers about 1/2 of the vertical usage.  Then when I drag the window, the layout manager recovers the remainder of the vertical space (as if there was no item present).

How can I force the behavior of moving the window?  I want the layout manager to completely recover the vertical space.

I am using Qt 5.6 on windows, but want cross-platform solutions.
Thank you,  mike

Comment: Do you call `updateGeometry` on the hidden widget?  A cut-down version of your code showing the problem would improve this question.

Comment: No - looks like `updateGeometry` is a no-op in this case.  Try `adjustSize` on the parent.

Comment: Hi Strubbly,  Thank you.  That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because laying out the widget is quite expensive, Qt doesn't always do it.  If you change the size of enclosed widgets you are likely to need to call `updateGeometry` on them to trigger the enclosed layout manager to re-layout.  But if you hide the widget, `updateGeometry` does nothing.  In that case you need to call `adjustSize` on the parent widget, which will then trigger the re-layout.